# What is this "_tkinter.TclError: bad option". can anybody tell me what I've done wrong and tell me how to fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

This is the code I tried at fix.

```py
label = tk.Label(frame1)
label.pack(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
```

I tried doing this but it says that I need to add `-anchor`, `-before`, `-expand`, `-fill`, `-in`, `-ipadx`, `-ipady`, `-padx`, `-pady`, or `-side`.

```py
label = tk.Label(frame1)
label.pack(anchor='n'r, elx=0.1, rely=0.1)
```

Comment: `relx`/`rely` are not meaningful options to `.pack()` - they're only used with `.place()`.  Just `label.pack()`, with no parameters, would make your widget visible - but you often need to use `side=`, `expand=`, or `fill=` to give it the right position and size relative to other widgets in the same container.

Comment: Thank you sooo muchh. I see the mistake I made, it was so simple, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Your help is greatly appriciated :))

Answer (score 0):

You should use `place()` instead `pack()`

So your code must be like this:

```py
label = tk.Label(frame1)
label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
```